# Generalizing a function with matrices

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, lubridate

I have a list of matrices, and I have a few different matrix that I would like to divide the elements in the list of matrices by. I would like to go down the list by sets of threes and calculate the difference between the minimum `jDate` for in `int1` and `int2`, as shown below for `n1`, `n2`,and `n3`. I would then like to divide the matrix created from these values `m1` from one of the matrix in the list. I would then move down to the next set of three elements in the list for `int1` and `int2` and calculate the differences between those, and repeat the same process as the first set of three. The output from the code below is the desired code, but when I change the number of days (i.e., 10 days) in `int1` and `int2` to something else like '7 days` the output is not desired. I was wondering what I can do to make the code more general so that no matter what I change the number of days to I will get the desired output.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("20-12-2013"), by = "days"), 500)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df$jDate <- julian(as.Date(df$date), origin = as.Date('1970-01-01'))
df$Month <- month(df$date)


t1 <- c(100,150,200)
t2 <- c(200,250,350)
t3 <- c(300,350, 400)
mat <- cbind(t1,t2, t3)

t1 <- c(150,150,200)
t2 <- c(250,250,350)
t3 <- c(350,350, 400)
mat2 <- cbind(t1,t2, t3)

l1 <- list(mat, mat2)

int1 <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%   # skipped for readability of result
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(Month == "3") %>% 
  group_split()

int2 <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%   # skipped for readability of result
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(Month == "2") %>% 
  group_split()

g1 <- as.integer(gl(length(int1), 3, length(int1)))
f1 <- function(.int1 ,.int2) {
  
  n1 <- c(((min(.int1[[1]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[1]]$jDate)),
          ((min(.int1[[1]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[2]]$jDate)),
          ((min(.int1[[1]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[3]]$jDate)))
  
  n2 <- c(((min(.int1[[2]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[1]]$jDate)),
          ((min(.int1[[2]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[2]]$jDate)),
          ((min(.int1[[2]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[3]]$jDate)))
  
  n3 <-  c(((min(.int1[[3]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[1]]$jDate)),
           ((min(.int1[[3]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[2]]$jDate)),
           ((min(.int1[[3]]$jDate))- min(.int2[[3]]$jDate)))
  out <- cbind(n1,n2,n3)
  out}

lstMat <- map2(split(int1, g1), split(int2, g1), ~  f1(.x, .y))
map2(l1, lstMat[1:2], `/`)
```

Comment: Are you changing both `10 day` and `days`

Comment: The issue is that you are filtering on different `Month` and the lengths are not the same when you change the value in `days`

Comment: Yeah I would be changing both. Is there a better way I can set this up?

Comment: February with less number of days creates the issue.  e.g. `day(new) == 31` is not true for all monthss

Comment: My actual data is like this, so I was hoping to simulate that as close as possible. Is there  a way to work around this?

Comment: why you are doing the `== 31`  I just wanted to understand the logic.  I

Comment: In other words, are you looking for an expression that checks the last day of each month instead of a constant 31

Comment: That's done because when I do the `10 day` intervals it places the dates `31` into its own list creating uneven an number of list between months that don't have 31 days and those that do.

Comment: If you do `int1 <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%   # skipped for readability of result
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '7 day')) %>% group_by(Month) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == max(day(new)), new - days(7), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(Month == "3") %>% 
  group_split()` it works

Comment: It doesn't work when its also changed in `int2`, at least for me. I would like the function to work when its changed in both `int1` and `int2`.

Comment: That is also because your `f1` function is fixed in assuming 3 elements each

Comment: You can try with `f2` I created in your other post `f2 <- function(.int1, .int2) {
   t(outer(seq_along(.int1), seq_along(.int2), 
      FUN = Vectorize(function(i, j)  min(.int1[[i]]$jDate) - 
           min(.int2[[j]]$jDate))))
}`